# Change header and column colours and font using HeaderFormatStyle in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Using ObjectListView how do I:

Change the background colour, foreground colour, and font attributes of a column's header and also the column itself.

I have looked here but it doesn't explain how to it either programmatically or in the IDE properly:

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-change-the-font-or-color-of-the-column-headers

Comment: From what I can tell, it does explain it sufficiently. What part of the description do you have trouble with understanding?

Comment: I tried this: OLVColumn.HeaderFormatStyle.SetBackColor(Color.Red); but this has not done anything; I did this inside the OLVColumn.AspoectGetter

Comment: More specifically: HearderFormatStyle h = new HeaderFormatStyle(); h.SetBackColor(Color.Red); olvColumn.HeeaderFormatStyle = h;

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise I needed to switch headerThemes to false

Comment: @azuric If you found the solution, please post it and accept it ;) or if you want you can also delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you switch headerThemes to false, then you can change the background colour, foreground colour, and font attributes.